# How do I show a loading image before actual body load?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide the body of my web page. Once the all content of the body tag of the web page are ready to display I want to show it body, but until that time I want to show some loading image.

If for some reason the content of the body does not load properly I want to show an error message.

What is the best way of doing this in javascript?

Comment: are you giving us instructions, or is there a question somewhere?

Comment: I've tried to make the english of this better, but if I changed the meaning can you correct it?

Answer (score 4):

It's pretty simple actually. You'll have to position a full screen `div` over your page and hide it once the `onload` function is triggered.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #loading-overlay {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1000;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            background-color: #003366;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="loading-overlay">This is a loading screen</div>

    <p>The page has loaded!</p>

    <!-- The following is to slow down the page load so that the effect can be observed -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.jsx=10"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.jsx=123"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.jsx=1232"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.jsx=12341"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.jsx=123459"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.jsx=1234568"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.jsx=12345677"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.jsx=1234567863"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.jsx=1234567891"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.jsx=1234567890"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.jsx=1234567890"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.jsx=1234567890"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.jsx=1234567890"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.jsx=1234567890"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.jsx=1234567890"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">        
        $(function() {
            $("#loading-overlay").hide();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to put both the div and the css before the head? Because I have a ton of css and javascript in-between that will have to be loaded in order for the div in the body tag to be even read.

Comment: That wouldn't be valid HTML.